# Do all NP-Complete problems run in $O(c^n)$ time, as opposed to $O(c^{n^k})$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, reductions, traveling-salesman

According to the [Wiki article on NP-Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Solving_NP-complete_problems), NP-Complete problems can be solved in $O(c^{n^k})$ time (I'll call this EXP-POLY time). However, shouldn't the bound on all their run times be the tighter $O(c^n)$ time (I'll call this simply EXP time)?

I ask because, for example, for the Traveling Salesman Problem, we can solve it exactly in EXP time ($O(n^2 2 ^n) \in O(3^n)$). To reduce any other problem to TSP, it'll add at most a polynomial term, which will still leave you with EXP time. There's no need to require EXP-POLY time at all, yeah?

Comment: What if your input size was $O(n^2)$ instead (which is still polynomially sized)? What would be the complexity of your TSP algorithm?

Comment: To answer your question, the size of the input here is what is different. Given a polynomially bounded size input (i.e input size is $O(n^k)$ for a constant $k$), you can indeed use TSP but the complexity will be $O(c^{size})$ where size is $O(n^k)$

Comment: $n$ is literally defined to be the size of the input, right? You can't just say arbitrarily that the size of the input is $n^k$, right?

Comment: $n$ is not the input size, the number of bits is (O($log n$) in ur example

Comment: @chausies: there is no problem with an input size $n^k$ or any other expression such as $me^{m}+y$, $n$ is not a "reserved identifier". This even makes sense in matrix computations, where an input size could be denoted $n^2$. Then the time for a product would be $O(n^3)$. [Vs. with an input size $n$, $O(n^{3/2})$.]